# How to get the index value in combo box?

Tags: c#, combobox

```
public class CustomComboItem
{
    public Double CodeValue { get; set; }
    public String DisplayName { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
  }

for (int i = 0; i < locCnt; ++i)
 { //I am setting member variable of  CustomComboItem
   // and add to the combobox
   ComboBox1.Items.Add(customComboItem1);
 }
```

So how  I can get the index of comboBox if I need to search by CodeValue.

Answer (score 0):

Use `foreach`

```
Int i = 0;

foreach(var item in myComboBox.Items)
{
    if(item.CodeValue = SearchCodeValue)
    {
        return i  // result index
    }
    else
    {
        i = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
var index = Array.FindIndex<CustomComboItem>(ComboBox1.Items.Cast<CustomComboItem>().ToArray<CustomComboItem>(), item => item.CodeValue == SearchCodeValue);
```